# ListView using ArrayList returns Android data address instead of string

Tags: android

When I use Array then contact data is shown but when I use ArrayList the screen displays Android data address (...Data@42c5). Any suggestions?

```
ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,rolelist); 
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Post some code, then only people here will be able to help you

Comment: not enough code...try this link to better understand listviews [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: I populated a vector with the arraylist contents and the contact information is displayed on the screen. Question is why does android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 display memory location and not data (string) stored at the location?

Comment: public ArrayList<ConatctData> rolelist = new ArrayList<ConatctData>();
    Vector display_roles = new Vector();

Comment: your code is not enough to check for error. Please put your activity code and layout code.

Answer (score 0):

By default it shows `item.toString()` for each `item` in `rolelist`.

Just override that method in your item class.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily understand the reason by referring createViewFromResource() [ which is called from getView() ] of ArrayAdapter.java, https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java
Check you have declared your ArrayList of type String.